# How to Transfer values to another class method

Tags: java, swing, methods

I have global variables in Question class and increments these values in event handler. I have another class User which contains a static method `Details()`. I want to pass these two variables values (after increments) from event handler to the `Details()` of the User class.:

```
public class Question {

    public int phCounter = 0;
    public int chemCounter = 0;

    private void CategoryCbActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

        phCounter++;
        chemCounter++;
    }
}
```

...

```
public class User {

    static void Details() {
        public counter ;
    }

}
```

My question is is there any way, except to send values as arguments to `Details()`, in which I can inject these incremented values inside `Details()` method.

Comment: Java doesn't have "global variables", so you don't have any. if you want another class to use your variables, pass them as a parameter to a method/constructor

Comment: what is `public counter ;`? What you are up to is not clear to me but where is the `datatype` of `counter`?

Answer (score 0):

First off: Method names in Java are camelCase. Not UpperCase ;)

If you want to access fields of a class in another class there are serveral ways to achieve that. The easiest one are static fields:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static String accessible;
}

public class AnotherClass {
    public void someMethod() {
        // You can set the value ...
        MyClass.accessible = "New value";
    }

    public void anotherMethod() {
        // ... and get the value.
        System.out.println(MyClass.accessible);
    }
}
```

But remember: The value of a static field will be always the same unless you change it, even when you create new instances of the class where the static field is used. You should avoid static fields if possible. In most cases you can take the OOP way to achieve the same result.

~ Morph

Comment: I have sent the value public int counter to the constructor of the User class but I need this value to be accessible from all the User class (like global variable) .

Comment: I want the int counter value to transfer to Details() of User class. But I have already called Details() from Question class with values name and age. so I used earlier User.Details(Bob, 30) and now I want to transfer counter value also to Details() but this time I do not need name and age arguments. I mean from one method of Question class, I called Details() with name and age and from another method of Question class I need to transfer counter value to Details()

Comment: If you really need to access the field (a class variable) across multiple classes, you can use a static field.

```java
public class MyClass {
    public static int myVar = 123;
}

public class AnotherClass {
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println(MyClass.myVar);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I can inject these incremented values inside Details() method.

what does this statement mean?

your code below can not be compiled!

```
public class User{
    static void Details()
    {
        public counter;
    }
}
```

if you want to use reflection to send args to method ,why not just call `User.Details(int a,int b)`